# No operator matches the given name and argument type in pg backed rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

First I implemented a sample search functionality a rails app using **SQLITE** as the database.

And the query was as follows:

`@productions = Production.where('productions.status like ?', "%#{params[:filter]}%")`

This worked fine. I was able to filter the record based on the statuses.

Now I am implementing same logic on a bigger app only difference is it is backed by **POSTGRESQL**

The logic

`@ride_later_requests = RideLaterRequest.where('ride_later_requests.status like ?', "%#{params[:filter]}%")`

When I hit filter this time I got some error saying

```
LINE 1: ...later_requests" WHERE (ride_later_requests.status like '%8%'...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT "ride_later_requests".* FROM "ride_later_requests" WHERE (ride_later_requests.status like '%8%')):
```

What am I doing wrong here ? Is this something related to pg ? Please help fix this.

**schema**

```
create_table "ride_later_requests", force: :cascade do |t|

    t.string   "customer_name"
    t.integer  "status"
end
```

**RideLaterRequest.rb**

```
enum status:{
    UnderConstruction:1,
    Submitted: 2,
    Unfulfilled:3,
    QuotesReady:4,
    Fulfilled: 5,
    Rejected:6,
    Ignored:7,
    Cancelled:8,
    Expired:9
  }
```

Comment: `@ride_later_requests = RideLaterRequest.where("status like ?", "%#{params[:filter]}%")` try this only

Comment: @Gabbar still same error. Pointing at `like`

Comment: `@ride_later_requests = RideLaterRequest.where("status LIKE ?", "%#{params[:filter]}%")` what about this?

Comment: still same now its showing error pointing at `LIKE`

Comment: What's the status data type?, can you share your schema?

Comment: @SebastianPalma added both schema and a part of model

Comment: Replicated your workflow and no problem, what could be the value for params[:filter]? are you trying to query by the enum key or value?

Comment: I am trying to query by key, the numbers `1` `2` etc. I have posted the logs too. It is taking `8` which is given to a certain status.

Comment: What Rails and Postgres version are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160301/discussion-between-user3576036-and-sebastian-palma).

Comment: Looks like `params[:filter]` here is `8`. @SebastianPalma

Comment: Yes, just I wanted to be sure :^).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what it's worth, I have two things:

1. Although `ActiveRecord#where` does input sanitization, it's typically good practice to validate your `params` has before it reaches a DB call.
2. I don't see the value with using the `like` operator when making the call to the DB in either case.  It seems you are locking the status down in an `enum` value, so you *should* be able to do `Production.where('status IS ?', params[:filter])`

I think you can also do it this way:

```
Production.where("status = ?", params[:filter])
```